# watir-classic: attach to existing browser getting error

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-classic

I am new to ruby and trying to attach to existing browser using watir-classic, but getting below exception.

```
Unable to locate a window with title of Google(Watir::Exception::NoMatchingWindowFoundException).
```

And, i am trying with the below code:

```
require 'Watir-classic'
browser = Watir::Browser.attach(:title, 'Google')
```

What is the wrong i was doing?

and i was trying with below code for 'WATIR'

require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new(
  :chrome, 
  'chromeOptions' => {'debuggerAddress': '127.0.0.1:8081'})

[image]

Comment: No, it works fine. I executed this code `require 'watir-classic'


b=Watir::Browser.attach(:title, "Google")

puts b.title`

Comment: Hi @RAJ, can you please let me know which browser and on which OS you have executed the script?

Comment: You are using WATIR-Classic, that's specific to IE. If you use WATIR(which uses selenium-webdriver), you could drive Firefox and Chrome as well. But WATIR doesn't have attachment function the one you used, only WATIR-classic has attach function.

Comment: I was trying with Microsoft Edge, but as per watir-classic documentation, it will supports till IE 20. Will that makes any problem? Pls. suggest

Comment: IE last version is 11 and then it moved to Edge, To drive the Edge browser you need driver for that you need to move to recent version of WATIR(Selenium Based). Watir-classic can only be used for IE which uses WIN32OLE to drive the browser. Use it for IE, it would work for you. Open the IE browser and try to connect, it would work.

Comment: Is there a reason you have chosen to learn Watir-Classic instead of mainline Watir? You're better of going mainline Watir since Watir-Classic isn't highly supported.

Comment: @RAJ, mainline Watir kind of supports [attaching to Chrome browsers](https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2017/09/15/attach-to-a-manually-opened-chrome-browser-using-debuggeraddress/). Not nearly as convenient, but might be good enough.

Comment: @JustinKo Yes, I recently read your article so I came to know that already! Thanks!

Comment: @JustinKo, I am trying with WATIR to attach to browser using the above mentioned link, but i am running into exception. Could you pls. help me out. I have updated the error in the question.

Comment: @BhanuprakashMankala, are you sure you (1) close all open Chrome browsers and (2) started Chrome with the remote-debugging-port flag?

Comment: @JustinKo, Yes. I have closed all the chrome browsers and started chrome with debugging port.

Comment: @BhanuprakashMankala, does starting Chrome normally - ie `browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome` - work in general?